# Android: How to make a special recyclerview layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, frontend

I'll describe my issue straight forward.
I have a bus application, and in some layout I need to display a the bus seats so the user can select one, and the display should follow the bus design.
as a backend developer i'm bringing the data, so when the data comes it is like this:

[image]

the client want to show the bus design (there are at max 10 designs), so the frontend developer did it this way (i didn't like it, because the data is corrupted):

[image]

it is clear that the data changed, he is doing it with this code (inside the adapter):

```
        if (position == 2 || position == 7 || position == 12 || position == 17 || position == 22 || position == 27 || position == 32 || position == 37 || position == 42 || position == 47) {
        holder.binding.seatNumber.setText("");
        holder.binding.seatNumber.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        index++;
    } else {
        holder.binding.seatNumber.setText(seatList.get(position - index).getSeatNumber() + "");
        if (seatList.get(position).isBooked()) {
            holder.binding.seatNumber.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.seat_bg_booked);
            holder.binding.seatNumber.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
```

which is clearly the wrong way, it is so random and messy, so I'm doing the search about this, how can we achieve this display with the real data?
consider the first layout ,having 45 seats,to be displayed:

column 0 and 1 = 20 seats

column 2 empty

columns 3 and 4 = 20 seats

the last 5 seats taking the whole last row.

please any solution or suggestion is appreciated, if you need more explanation tell me.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change if condition in the adapter class

```
holder.binding.seatNumber.setText(seatList.get(position - index).getSeatNumber() + "");
        if (seatList.get(position - index).isBooked()) {
            holder.binding.seatNumber.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.seat_bg_booked);
                holder.binding.seatNumber.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can  achieve this by adding two type to layouts in your adapter . To learn  how to use two different layout in recyclerview article is [here](https://medium.com/@droidbyme/android-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type-multiple-view-holder-af798458763b)